# UIKeyboardInputManagerClassForInputMode

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am still having a memory leak and the performance tool-> leak; is coming back referencing the above title. The responsible library is UIKit and it is a malloc/w 128 bytes?  It happens when in my UITableView I press/select the first cell. Has anyone ran into this before, can someone test this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is only happens in the simulator not in actual device. Seems like bug on apple.